# c# List.Exists returns true with "false && true"

Tags: c#, list, boolean, operator-keyword, exists

So I was working on a Program and was a little bit confused about the behavior of a Listoperator. I have a List and wanted to know if it holds an entry according to some criterias.
Now let's call it a List and obj has the following Properties:

```
public string PropA { get; set; }
public string PropB { get; set; }
public string PropC { get; set; }
public bool HasPropC { get; set; }
```

Now I only wanted a true result if PropA was equal to one in the list and if the property in the List has as PropC it should check PropC, otherwise PropB.
I used this piece of code for it:

```
 if (List.Exists(x => {
       bool b = true;

       b = b && x.PropA.Equals(obj.PropA);
       b = b && x.HasPropC ? x.PropC.Equals(obj.PropC) : x.PropB.Equals(obj.PropB);

       return b;
}))
```

After the first line with the "PropA.Equals..." b was set to false. But the line beyond made it true again. So it seemed like there was an Object even it was not. I found a solution for it, I wrapped the second Line after the &&-Operator into brackets but I still don't know why it made out of a false a true.

Can you give me a hint on this one?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to change it to `b = b && (x.HasPropC ? x.PropC.Equals(obj.PropC) : x.PropB.Equals(obj.PropB));` Otherwise it's ANDing `b` and `x.HasPropC` and using that to determine which part of the conditional to execute and assign to `b`.

Answer (score 6):

In the expression

```
b && x.HasPropC ? x.PropC.Equals(obj.PropC) : x.PropB.Equals(obj.PropB);
```

The `&&` operator has precedence over the `?:` operator. So, when you evaluated it, `b && x.HasPropC` has been evaluated to false, and `b` was assigned with the value `x.PropB.Equals(obj.PropB)`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere OP already explained he managed to solve the problem (using braces to disable the operator precedence), and was simply asking for clarification as to why this was happening.